# Swift XMLParser // Select node based on element & attribute

Tags: swift, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XMLParser with Swift that is working great. However from time to time there are nodes that come up with the same name as the actual nodes I want. So when these extra nodes show up, is messes everything up. Here is an example of the good scenario. This has been simplified a bit to help explain.

```
<master>
    <inputs>
        <input>
        <input>
    </inputs>
    <overlays>
        <overlay number="1">4</overlay>
        <overlay number="2">7</overlay>
    </overlays>
</master>
```

But sometime this happens and messes up my code.

```
<master>
    <inputs>
        <input>
             <overlay index="0"/>
        </input>
    </inputs>
    <overlays>
        <overlay number="1">4</overlay>
        <overlay number="2">7</overlay>
    </overlays>
</master>
```

I need to select only the "Overlay" within the "Overlays" elements and retrieve the value in between the tags. I don't know how to select this specifically. Here are the 2 main parser functions I currently have where the general node "Overlay" is noted instead of the specific "Overlays"

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if elementName == "overlay" {
            OverlayValue = ""
    }
}
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    OverlayValue?.append(string)
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "overlay" {
        OverlayXML.append(OverlayArray(value: OverlayValue!))
        OverlayValue = nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've needed to deal with this I've used a few instance variables to keep track of where I am.

```
var inInputs = false
var inOverlays = false
```

Then update your `didStartElement` to look for "inputs" and set `inInputs = true`. And look for `overlays` and set `inOverlays = true`. Do the same for `didEndElement` but set the flags back to `false`.

Then you can update your `if elementName == "overlay" {` to `if elementName == "overlay" && inOverlays {`. Make a similar change for `input`.

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if elementName == "overlays" {
        inOverlays = true
    } else if elementName == "inputs" {
        inInputs = true
    } else if elementName == "overlay" && inOverlays {
        OverlayValue = ""
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "overlays" {
        inOverlays = false
    } else if elementName == "inputs" {
        inInputs = false
    } else if elementName == "overlay" && inOverlays {
        OverlayXML.append(OverlayArray(value: OverlayValue!))
        OverlayValue = nil
    }
}
```